# Conditionally append or remove sub-elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a complex graph that has lines with text on them; however, there are performance issues (SVG gets a bit too busy). I would like to be able to toggle whether the text is rendered or not. Here is a simplified example, with the intention that the text should be rendered or not depending on the value of the checkbox:

```js
const data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
const svg = d3.select('#graph');
const g = svg.append('g');

function render(data, showText) {
  const lineG = g.selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .join('g')
  lineG.append('path')
    .attr('d', (d, i) => `M10,${(i + 1) * 30} l100,0`)
    .attr('id', (d, i) => `line-${i}`)
    .attr('stroke', 'black');
    
  if (showText) { // wrong approach
  
    lineG.append('text')
      .attr('dy', -2)
      .append('textPath')
        .attr('href', (d, i) => `#line-${i}`)
        .text(d => d);
  }
}

render(data, true);
d3.select('#toggleText')
  .on('click', evt => {
    const checked = evt.target.checked;
    render(data, checked);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<svg id="graph" width="300" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
<br>
<label><input id="toggleText" type="checkbox" checked>Show text</label>
```

This does not work, and I know why. But I cannot figure out how to do this correctly in the D3 paradigm. Note that it is easy to toggle whether the text is *visible* or not; this is not what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anything else, you should not use `lineG` like that: you're appending a new path every time you click the checkbox.

The idiomatic D3 approach is using enter/update/exit selections. That would be something like this...

```
let text = lineG.selectAll(".myTextClass")
  .data((_, i) => showText ? [i] : []);

text.exit().remove();

const textEnter = text.enter()
  .append('text')
  .attr("class", "myTextClass")
  .attr('dy', -2);

textEnter.append('textPath')
  .attr('href', (d) => `#line-${d}`)
  .text(d => "foo");

text = textEnter.merge(text);
```

... working on `lineG`. D3 is pretty verbose, and the above snippet is even more, given we have to append a `<textPath`>  under the `<text>`.

Also, here I'm not using the indices (since each group has just one text), but instead passing the parent's index through the data:

```
.data((_, i) => showText ? [i] : []);
```

Here is the working demo:

```js
const data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
const svg = d3.select('#graph');
const g = svg.append('g');

function render(data, showText) {
  const lineG = g.selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .join('g')
  lineG.append('path')
    .attr('d', (d, i) => `M10,${(i + 1) * 30} l100,0`)
    .attr('id', (d, i) => `line-${i}`)
    .attr('stroke', 'black');

  let text = lineG.selectAll(".myTextClass")
    .data((_, i) => showText ? [i] : []);

  text.exit().remove();

  const textEnter = text.enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr("class", "myTextClass")
    .attr('dy', -2);

  textEnter.append('textPath')
    .attr('href', (d) => `#line-${d}`)
    .text(d => "foo");

  text = textEnter.merge(text);

}

render(data, true);
d3.select('#toggleText')
  .on('click', evt => {
    const checked = evt.target.checked;
    render(data, checked);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<svg id="graph" width="300" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
<br>
<label><input id="toggleText" type="checkbox" checked>Show text</label>
```

If you need the data for something else, just try another way of passing the parent's index, like a local variable or `selection.each()`. For instance:

```js
const data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
const svg = d3.select('#graph');
const g = svg.append('g');
const local = d3.local();

function render(data, showText) {
  const lineG = g.selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .join('g')
  lineG.append('path')
    .attr('d', (d, i) => `M10,${(i + 1) * 30} l100,0`)
    .attr('id', (d, i, n) => {
      local.set(n[i].parentNode, i);
      return `line-${i}`
    })
    .attr('stroke', 'black');

  let text = lineG.selectAll(".myTextClass")
    .data(d => showText ? [d] : []);

  text.exit().remove();

  const textEnter = text.enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr("class", "myTextClass")
    .attr('dy', -2);

  textEnter.append('textPath')
    .attr('href', (_, i, n) => `#line-${local.get(n[i])}`)
    .text(d => d);

  text = textEnter.merge(text);

}

render(data, true);
d3.select('#toggleText')
  .on('click', evt => {
    const checked = evt.target.checked;
    render(data, checked);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<svg id="graph" width="300" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
<br>
<label><input id="toggleText" type="checkbox" checked>Show text</label>
```

Comment: Oh, this looks pretty much exactly like what I imagined it should be, only... working :)

Comment: Actually, can I ask one more thing though? As you can see my experience with d3 is very lacking - could you modify your code so that the original array is being shown, instead of "foo"? I am not sure how to implement "If you need the data for something else, just try another way of passing the parent's index, like a local variable or `selection.each()`." (Nested `data` break my brain)

Comment: @Amadan sure thing, have a look at the second snippet, using local variables (I reckon they are easier to understand than `selection.each`). And if nested data breaks your brain... welcome, you're not alone.

Answer (score 1):

Note that whenever you use `.append` on non-empty selections you're adding elements. So in your render function you're adding elements every single time you call it.

For this answer, I run `render` only once, but if you want to run it multiple times, you should read up on using [selection.join](https://observablehq.com/@d3/selection-join) for the general update pattern.

Instead of calling `render` multiple times, you can instead update only the text, adding and removing it with `append` and `remove`. I've included an example below:

```js
const data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
const svg = d3.select('#graph');
const g = svg.append('g');

var lineG;
function render(data) {
  lineG = g.selectAll('g')
    .data(data)
    .join('g');

  lineG.append('path')
    .attr('d', (d, i) => `M10,${(i + 1) * 30} l100,0`)
    .attr('id', (d, i) => `line-${i}`)
    .attr('stroke', 'black');    
}
var textShown = null;
function updateText(showText) {
  if (textShown === showText) {
    return;
  }
  if (showText) {
    lineG
      .append('text')
      .attr('dy', -2)
      .append('textPath')
        .attr('href', (d, i) => `#line-${i}`)
        .text(d => d);
  } else {
    lineG.selectAll('text').remove()
  }
  textShown = showText;
}

render(data);
updateText(d3.select('#toggleText').property('checked'));
d3.select('#toggleText')
  .on('click', evt => {
    const checked = evt.target.checked;
    updateText(checked);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
<svg id="graph" width="300" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"></svg>
<br>
<label><input id="toggleText" type="checkbox" checked>Show text</label>
```

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I know about the join pattern (I am using it in the sample above for the lines). I was wondering if a sub-join or something with a one-element or zero-element datum might make sense to automatically add/remove the text, but manually doing it is actually not too ba.d Thanks.